# Duplicates values in Map: Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I have a scenario whereby I need a map containing duplicate keys and values. I have created a list first and then I used associatedBy to convert them to a map, however the duplicates issue is not taken into account. Here is my implementation:

```
class State(private val startStatus: Status, private val expectedStatus: Status) {
  
  companion object StatusList {
    val listStatuses = listOf(
      State(Status.A, Status.B),
      State(Status.B, Status.A),
      State(Status.B, Status.C),
      State(Status.C, Status.B),
      State(Status.C, Status.E),
      State(Status.C, Status.D),
      State(Status.D, Status.B),
      State(Status.E, Status.C),
      State(Status.E, Status.B)
    )
  
    open fun mapStatuses(): Map<Status, Collection<Status>> {
      return listStatuses.associateBy(
        keySelector = { key -> key.expectedStatus },
        valueTransform = State::startStatus)
    }
  }
}
```

I am struggling to find a Multimap in Kotlin that would allow me to deal with duplicates. Can you help?

Thanks

Comment: Change `associateBy` to `groupBy` in your code. That should be all you need.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In short, there is no multimap in Kotlin.

A multimap would allow multiple, equivalent keys with different values - this can be implemented with unique keys and a collection of values associated with given key, instead of having a view over collection of key-value pairs with equivalent keys.

Thus, you can use `groupBy()`:

```
data class Record(val id: Int, val name: String)

fun main() {
    val records = listOf(
            Record(1, "hello"),
            Record(1, "there"),
            Record(2, "general"),
            Record(2, "kenobi")
    )

    val mapped = records.groupBy({ it.id }, { it.name })

    for (entry in mapped) {
        println("${entry.key} -> ${entry.value.joinToString()}")
    }
}
```

Here I am using `groupBy` with a *projection* of key (which is `Record`'s `id`) and a *projection* of value (which is `Record`'s `name`). Quite similar to your `State`s and `Status`es.

Comment: Thanks, but groupBy gives me exactly the same result. The issue is that I am not only have the same key -> different values I also have different key -> same values. I do not seem to find a fit solution

Comment: What is the problem then? Different key -> same value is acceptable for a plain `Map`. Can you clarify? What are your exact requirements?